# error when matching url from gmail body using google app script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I am newbie to Google Apps Script can some one please help me to match url from gmail body using google's app script below is the script i have tried but I am getting error when matching it from email body. I am able to get full message in variable `mailmsg` but I am failed to match it I have also pasted my mail body below I want to extract first https link from mail body

here is match statement

```
     var mailmsg = message[t][x].getPlainBody();
     var regexpmatch = mailmsg.match(/^(https?|chrome):\/\/[^\s$.?#].[^\s]*$/)[1];
     Logger.log(regexpmatch);
```

below is my email body from gmail

Download Data

```
 <https://testurl.ct.testdata.net/ls/click?upn=9VwHM0E24WA-2F- 
  2FuwWpvo09QzByap8Q1XZ3lwZOYwqoN3DdeK6YUcVokkOb2-2Boq9zJ4ZMqKkeFvE-2FkR1Rugi1jarDEORU- 
  2BZtK6x7Wjz0bDlMzaGaJTMEqlbz4WU8125U4HpFoz_bacS4DOsuE1jq
```

Thanks,

Your Team

```
 <https://testurl.ct.testdata.net/ls/click?upn=UHpyaFHJ1bhBoqAjtHiHtIMeBu-2FwtyBJ- 
 2Fi9JleFeKj10XIQWU1NH69-2FFIhuNafdc2XG7_bacS4DOsuE1jq
```

Comment: Try this: `/https:\/\/[^\s]{1,}/gm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extract the url, you can use this:

```
var regexpmatch = mailmsg.match(/https:\/\/[^\s]{1,}/gm)
```